# Is there a way to cache Python 3.5 definitions using a time-to-live decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching

Currently, I use `functools`' `lru_cache` to handle my caching for the function. The problem is that the size of the cache never grows large enough to make use of the `LRU` (due to the fact that the function never takes in a parameter). Instead, the function, when called, opens up a specific URL and return its contents.

Is there a way in which I can specify the 'time to live' cache in which after a certain amount of time/certain amount of calls, it refreshes its cache?

Comment: I don't understand your caching rules. Does the function just return one thing many times? If there are no parameters to this url, how would you know that a potential return value is locally cached?

Comment: I asked the question because it sounds like you don't want an lru cache at all. It sounds like you want to use the url return value for a set period of time and then refresh it. Can you confirm in some way?

Comment: @tdelaney so the resource I am getting from the URL occasionally updates (as in once per every few hours). I would like the function to cache the return value of the function, but also update it's cache every set few hours in case the webpage updates.

Comment: So, yes - I don't want to use LRU cache. I Agree with what you just said. I just want to cache the return value and update the cache after a set amount time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a decorator, but you can keep track of the last time you got the page and update as needed. If this is a single-threaded app, it can be simple

```
_cached_page = ''
_cached_page_time = 0

def get_page():
    global _cached_page, _cached_page_time
    now = time.time()
    # invalidate in 1 hour
    if not _cached_page or now - _cached_page_time > 60 * 60:
        _cached_page = get_the_page_here()
        _cached_page_time = time.time()
    return _cached_page
```

You could also age the page with a timer in the background. You need to control access with a lock, but that makes the cache usable in a multithreaded program too.

```
_cached_page = ''
_cached_page_lock = threading.Lock()

def _invalidate_page():
    global _cached_page
    with _cached_page_lock:
        _cached_page = ''

def get_page():
    global _cached_page
    with _cached_page_lock:
        if not _cached_page:
            _cached_page = get_the_page_here()
            # invalidate in 1 hour
            threading.Timer(60*60, _invalidate_page)
        return _cached_page
```

Finally, the server may include an `Expires: ...` field in the http header. Depending on how well the service was written, this would be a good reflection of how long the page can be cached.

Answer (score 1):

The [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) function accepts a `maxsize` argument which saves the results up to the `maxsize` most recent calls.

You can check this by calling the `cache_info` attribute of your decorated function.

If you want to refresh your cache completely you should implement a cash object manually by counting the number of cache calls and resetting the cache whenever it hits the max size.

```
from functools import wraps


class Mycache(object):
    def __init__(self, maxcount):
        self.count = 0
        self.maxcount = maxcount
        self.cache = {}

    def __call__(self, func):

        @wraps(func)
        def wrapped(*args):
            self.count += 1
            if self.count > self.maxcount:
                self.cache = {}
                self.count = 0
                result = self.cache[args] = func(*args)
            else:
                try:
                    result = self.cache[args]
                except KeyError:
                    result = self.cache[args] = func(*args)
            return result
        return wrapped
```

Demo:

```
@Mycache(3)
def a(arg):
    print("arg is : {}".format(arg))
    return arg ** 2

print(a(4))
print(a(4))
print(a(4))
print(a(4))
print(a(3))
print(a(4))
```

output:

```
arg is : 4
16
16
16
arg is : 4
16
arg is : 3
9
16
```

Comment: OP says the function doesn't take a parameter.... sounds to me like lru is not what he wants, regardless of its parameterization.

Comment: @tdelaney I'm not sure of that, but I think there might be some other ways by implementing a custom memoizer decorator.