# Use JSON data throughout my code

Tags: python, json, django, django-models

I'm new to Django and would appreciate any kind of help.

I request my JSON with this following function inside my app's services.py

```
def get_games():
    url = "https://igdbcom-internet-game-database-v1.p.mashape.com/games/"
    headers = {"X-Mashape-Key": "12131221"}
    # Pop the Offset with ajax When user reaches the end of the page
    params = {"filter[release_dates.date][gte]": datetime.date.today(),
              "fields": '*',
              "limit": 50,
              "order": "release_dates.date:desc",
              "offset": 0}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
    games = r.json()
    # Returns JSON Array
    return games
```

The JSON gets back to me just fine, but how can I use the JSON array I get from the function above throughout my code? My Homepage's view calls the get_games() function and then it sends the JSON data to a template called game_list.html. From there, I parse my JSON and  I get to display the information from the web api on my website.

```
class HomePage(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request):
        games = services.get_games()
        # Sends the json string to the template
        return render(request, 'releases/game_list.html', {"games": games})
```

Now the problem arises when I make any other kind of view, I can't get to work with the JSON I got from above. "Normally, we grab data from the database in the models.py file, but I am unsure if I should be grabbing this API data in models.py or views.py". My site has zero models, can I maybe create some and somehow put the JSON data in the models, but then I'll have to request only on my side and not the client's side (everytime he access the homepage) or maybe cache the json data?

Thanks, real sorry if I sound confusing, I confused myself, thanks once again.

Comment: I am confused. Why not you can call the `get_games()` from the another view? If you are sure that content won't change and it is something which is called too frequent OR, has loads of data, only then go for database. Even better if your store in redis/memcache for some session/duration if it expires after sometime

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you are after but I answered a question about a time-to-live cache the other day here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40686517/642070. `get_games` could cache the data and only refresh it after some period of time. This is a primitive cache of 1 piece of data but these things can scale up with lru caches or even something big like memcache.

Comment: Any caching system examples?

Comment: [Django’s cache framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/) is a good start!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use `json.loads` to convert the json data to a Python object, so your view would look as follows:

```
class HomePage(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request):
        games = json.loads(services.get_games())
        # Sends the games object to the template
        return render(request, 'releases/game_list.html', {"games": games})
```

**Edit:**

I do not think that you need to use models in this case. Storing the resulted data in your end or requesting the remote service each time depends on your use case, if getting the last updated data is not a must for you then you can use some kind of cache to store the returned json. I usually use Redis to cache my data in such cases.

**To use Redis as Django's cache backend, follow the below steps:**

Install `redis-server`:

```
sudo apt-get install redis-server
```

Install `django-redis-cache` in your virtual environment:

```
pip install django-redis-cache
```

Add the following to your settings.py file:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'redis_cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379',
        'TIMEOUT': 24*3600  # example of 1 day
    }
}
```

To use Django's cache in your view:

```
import json
from django.core.cache import cache


class HomePage(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request):
        games = cache.get('games')
        if not games:
            games = json.dumps(services.get_games())
            # Store data in Redis
            cache.set('games', games)
        return render(request, 'releases/game_list.html', {"games": json.loads(games)})
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with my question. I just want to be able to use the JSON data I got in another view instead of requesting it each time in each view, but thank you.l

Comment: @JamesA Please check my edited answer and let me know if it helps you.

Comment: Ye it sure helps but can you give me an example of how to use a caching system a link would be fine and with my json cached, can I access it in whatever template/views I want?

Comment: These two libraries may help you: https://github.com/sebleier/django-redis-cache, https://github.com/niwinz/django-redis

Comment: @JamesA Take a look at the example that I added above (it is using `django-redis-cache`)